# When I type any property on css in vscode, let's say text-transform,I don't get relevant value suggestions,such as uppercase,How to get them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

This is what I want

[image: 1]

I tried changing all the vscode suggestions settings and also enabled all "show suggestion" settings on my workspace(workspace only,not in user)

Comment: What's the current language mode in the open editor? You can change language mode with the `Change Language Mode` command. Once you set the language mode, you should get what you want. VS Code ships with such CSS support out-of-box (no extensions required).

Comment: I did selected the current language as css(instead of auto detect) but still I don't get specific suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can go to extensions, search for CSS and install the first extension. Once installed, you will get the predictions.

Eg: HTML CSS Support extension.